# Windows 7 Startup Repair Tool "recovered" Windows by moving it to another drive: how do I move it back?

Tags: windows-7, bootrepair, repair-install

My original Windows 7 installation was on my C drive (an SSD), and somehow became corrupted and unbootable.

After running the Startup Repair Tool a new Windows folder has been created on D:\, and the system will boot from there - but of course it's very slow. All programs have been linked correctly and work.

The original C:\Windows still exists, but booting from there fails.

Is there a way to either move the Windows folder back to where it was? I have a lot of software installed in both drives, so not enough room to clone an entire disk.

Comment: How can `C:\Windows` work if you cannot boot from it?

Comment: It doesn't work, it reboots if I try. I have the choice of my original Windows install (on C:\) and the "recovered" one (on D:\).